# Начальная конфигурация программы в проектах типа ClassLibrary (Net standard2.0)

Tags: c#, .net-standard

В туториале по "Linq To DB" написано

.Net Core does not support System.Configuration so to configure connection strings you should implement ILinqToDBSettings, for example:

, что по русски означает ".Net Core не поддерживает System.Configuration, поэтому для конфигурирования connection strings необходимо реализовать ILinqToDBSettings, например:

```
'''c#
public class ConnectionStringSettings : IConnectionStringSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public bool IsGlobal => false;
}

public class MySettings : ILinqToDBSettings
{
    public IEnumerable<IDataProviderSettings> DataProviders => Enumerable.Empty<IDataProviderSettings>();

    public string DefaultConfiguration => "SqlServer";
    public string DefaultDataProvider => "SqlServer";

    public IEnumerable<IConnectionStringSettings> ConnectionStrings
    {
        get
        {
            yield return
                new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = "SqlServer",
                    ProviderName = "SqlServer",
                    ConnectionString = @"Server=.\;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;Enlist=False;"
                };
        }
    }
}
'''
```

And later just set on program startup before the first query is done (Startup.cs for example): (А затем просто установите в запуске программы,например Startup.cs,  до первого вызова):

DataConnection.DefaultSettings = new MySettings();

Но если я делаю dll-ку в проекте ClassLibrary (Net standard2.0), то в этом проекте нет ни Startup.cs, ни каких-либо других файлов, которые бы запускались до запуска программы.

Может кто знает, как в проекте ClassLibrary (Net standard2.0) конфигурировать приложение, в частности connectionstring? Либо какие тут могут быть аналоги Startup.cs или app.config или web.config, имеющие место в других проектах?

Comment: Это как бы "переносимая библиотека классов", у Вас просто морального права нет хардкодить туда какое-то подключение. Вы должны из stable-проекта наоборот передавать данные о желаемом подключении в свою библиотеку

Comment: Да, наверное, так оно и есть...